# How to capture the system sound output, but not the microphone?

Tags: sound, input-devices

This is my `$Version`

> `"11.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (May 16, 2017)"`

We have two methods to record sounds in *Mathematica* if we are in *11.1*.

- `SystemDialogInput["RecordSound"]`
- `AudioCapture[]`

But this two methods both cannot exclude those sounds in surroundings if you are recording from the microphone. I just want to record the system sounds output from the computer and not from a microphone.

**So can we tell Mathematica to capture the system sound output without recording the microphone input?**

Currently available devices are:

```
 $AudioOutputDevices
```

> [image]

Comment: This is a problem of acoustics, not the computer language *Mathematica*.  There are all manner of baffling and microphoning tricks, but you should explore them elsewhere.

Comment: The approach depends deeply on several factors (indoors, outdoors, one microphone, two, voice versus non-voice, etc.) and there are several solutions that are not appropriate to discuss on this site, since they have nothing to do with *Mathematica*.  You should search elsewhere.

Comment: @yode, can you clarify? Based on "So can we just record those sounds just from sound card?" it sounds like you're wanting to record the sounds that your computer is outputting and not the sounds picked up by a microphone.

Comment: @N.J.Evans Yes,yes yes..

Comment: @rhermans Thanks,and could you help to delete those explaining comments(mine David G. Stork's and yours) in case misunderstanding?:)

Comment: @yode, On my machine `$AudioOutputDevices` returns `{Built-in Output, Display Audio}`. I can do `AudioCapture["test.wav",AudioInputDevice->"Display Output"]`. The sound quality is kind of bad, but it does work.

Comment: @N.J.Evans Sad,I don't include that item.This is [my result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XCQDc.png).

Comment: @yode, I edited significantly your question, please check that I didn't distort the meaning you actually intended. (roll back if my edit is wrong). I still think this may be off-topic. Anyhow, I provided an answer that works for me. The availability of *"Stereo Mix"*  depends on the details of your system, audio card and drivers, so there are not guarantees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Windows

Idea copied from [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/217348/how-to-record-the-sound-coming-from-your-pc-even-without-stereo-mix/).

---

On the volume tray icon, right click and select "Recording Devices"

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Be sure that disabled devices are listed. Tick *"Show Disabled Devices"*

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You may have a device called *"Stereo Mix"* , *"What U Hear"* or *"Rec. Playback"*.
Enable the device if it is disabled. Now check that is listed in [`$AudioInputDevices`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$AudioInputDevices.html), and notice the position of the device in the list.

```
TableForm[$AudioInputDevices, TableHeadings -> Automatic]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Now you can specify the device using [`AudioInputDevice`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AudioInputDevice.html)

```
AudioCapture[
 "test.ogg"
 , AudioInputDevice -> $AudioInputDevices[[2]] 
 , Appearance -> "Detailed"
 , SampleRate -> Automatic
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

**Mac OS**

1. Install SoX (the Swiss Army knife of sound processing programs.)

   > brew install sox
2. Install Loopback (Route audio between applications on your Mac.)

   https://rogueamoeba.com/loopback/
3. Create a virtual audio input device which routes the audio from Safari as input.(Don't forget to tick the checkbox to activate it)
   [image]
4. Select the virtual audio input device as the default audio input device.
   [image]
5. Record and play

In:

RunProcess[{"open", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0MK7qz13bU"}];
RunProcess[{"/usr/local/bin/rec", "-c", "2", "radio.aiff", "trim", 
  "0", "0:10"}]
RunProcess[{"/usr/local/bin/play", "radio.aiff"}]

Out:

[image]

Comment: +1.  Does `AudioCapture` work on MacOS? Is the virtual loopback showing up in `$AudioInputDevices`?

Comment: No.There is no such API available on macOS. It is showing up in $AudioOutputDevices at least. There is something wrong with my audio input devices/drivers, $AudioInputDevices is empty.